# Wordpress - Id's para imágenes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-imagenes

Estoy realizando un site en wordpress para probar de crear mi propio tema.
La cuestión es que al obtener la ruta de la imagen, este me printa, además, el ID del post.

Código PHP:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="entrada">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            //El wp_get_attachment_url me devuelve la imagen, y a su vez el ID se muestra
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( the_ID() ), 'full' );
        ?>
            <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>);">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="entrada_info">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <small>Publicado el <?php the_time('j/m/Y'); ?> por <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No hay entradas .'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

El objetivo era obtener la imagen destacada que se asignó al post, y ponerla como fondo en el `div` thumbnail. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero como digo, también me printa el ID:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayer estuve buscando la manera de obtener las imágenes y lo que encontré fue con ese trozo de código, pero no vi en ningún momento nadie diciendo que eso también muestra el id.

¿Alguna manera de quitar ese ID?

**Añado**
El `background-image` me lo devuelve bien:

**Añado**
Imagen del código resultante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<a href="http://wp:9998/2017/01/24/faltan-75-dias-para-el-mobile-world-congress/" style="background-image: url(http://wp:9998/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1482499331.png);"></a>
```

Pero la variable `$image` que declaro arriba me sigue devolviendo el id.

Comment: en la linea `background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>">` no se deberia cerrar el parentesis de **`url`**: "`url(<?php echo $image; ?>)">`" ?

Comment: @lois6b he probado de quitar el div, solamente almacenando en la variable `$image` la URL, sin hacer ningún echo ni var_dump ni nada, pero incluso solo con eso me muestra el id.

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo de la imagen junto al ID que te está generando en HTML?

Comment: @lois6b acabo de añadir el resultado. El background me lo devuelve bien, pero simplemente me muestra el 10 como un string, sin más debajo de donde está el `<div class="entrada">`

Comment: Un string sin mas como, en que etiqueta?

Comment: @lois6b justo después del div con la clase entrada, como si se hiciera un echo en la misma línea donde está, acabo de añadir la imagen del código resultante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `the_ID()` que estás usando dentro de `get_post_thumbnail_id( the_ID() )`, no devuelve el id, **lo pinta**.

E.g, lo que estás haciendo es equivalente a `get_post_thumbnail_id( echo get_the_ID() )`;

Tienes que usar `get_the_ID()` (que devuelve el valor, y no lo pinta):

```
get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() )
```

La [documentación](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) es tu amiga. :)

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_thumbnail_id()` obtiene la ID de la imagen. Si usas `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` te devuelve la url y ya puedes hacer echo con ella. Mucho más fácil y cómodo.